# AS3 - Array containing MovieClips, indexOf

Tags: arrays, flash, actionscript-3

I have this Array and these event handlers:

```
var btnArr:Array = new Array(aBtn, bBtn, cBtn);
aBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, blah);
bBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, blah);
cBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, blah);
```

Where aBtn, bBtn and cBtn are MovieClip objects.

When I try and get the index of one of these, during an event:

```
function blah(e:Event) {
     var i = btnArr.indexOf(e.target);
     trace(i)
```

So why does this trace return an `undefined` every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use e.currentTarget  , e.target may be some child . Or like Tobias says - set mouseChildren to false

Comment: I have now implemented both of these suggestions, still no joy I'm afraid. The `trace(i)` still comes back `undefined`.

I also have other traces like these:
`trace(e)`
`trace(e.currentTarget)`

Which output: `[MouseEvent type="mouseOut" bubbles=true cancelable=false eventPhase=2 localX=-4 localY=-14 stageX=103.45 stageY=35.95 relatedObject=null ctrlKey=false altKey=false shiftKey=false buttonDown=false delta=0]` and
`[object MovieClip]` respectively.

Comment: Using curretTarget seems to have solved the problem, I'm getting the correct indexes in my trace now. Thanks very much! Got a wholly unrelated problem to deal with now! I assure you if it's not solved by this evening I'll be posting it...

Answer (score 0):

Where do you initialize the buttons? Did you try to trace the MovieClip name? Perhaps your MovieClip has children that are dispatching your event. Try to set `mouseChildren = false.`

Comment: Would it be easier for me to post my whole code somewhere? The buttons are instances of symbols I drew on the stage. I did trace the clip name, but because I'm trying to get the index of the object in the array that didn't seem to help me much. I had thought of a very sticky workaround, but that isn't going well either.

Comment: If you add an EventListener to a MovieClip that has other DisplayObjects as childs, than the event is dispatched from them and not from your symbol itself. The event is "bubbling". So e.target is the DisplayObject inside your Button. And that is why your indexOf function returns undefined. Use e.currentTarget like turbosqel said. The currentTarget is your button. The Object you added your EventHandler to. Or set the mouseChildren property of your button to false.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me. I get 0,1,2 respectfully.
So I will assume here that you did "not" give your MovieClip buttons the instance name of aBtn,bBtn,cBtn
Which would be undefined.
Although, it should throw a compile time error.

And please learn to type cast all your vars it will only help you in the long run.

```
var i:int = btnArr.indexOf(e.target);
```

Answer (score 0):

Array's indexOf should return -1 if it can not find the element.

Since you are getting undefined, are you sure btnArr is the Array you created before?